# How to insert footnotes automatically with glossaries package?

Tags: footnotes, glossaries

I have list of acronyms which are defined with `\newacronym` command e.g., `\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}`.
I need to insert footnote automatically just once, if the command `\acrshort{gcd}` is used.
For this purpose i use the following command:

`\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\glsgenentryfmt \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{\footnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}}}`

**The problem**: for each `\acrshort{gcd}` command, one footnote is inserted but i need the footnote is inserted on the first use of the command, like the `\gls{gcd}` command. When the `\gls{gcd}` command is used, the footnote only inserted on the first use of the command.

Here is the minimal not working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{%
  \glsgenentryfmt \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{\footnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}}
}

\begin{document}

\acrfull{gcd}\\
\acrshort{gcd} \\
\acrshort{gcd} \\
%\gls{gcd} \\
%\gls{gcd} \\

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: From the documentation: "The `\acr…` commands described below are part of the set of `\glstext`-like commands.
That is, they index and can form hyperlinks, and they **don’t modify or test the first use flag**." (emphasis mine) So what you are trying to do is directly against the design of the package.

Comment: basically: the glossaries package already built the `\gls` command to do what you want it to do, and designed the `\acroshort` command to not do what you want it to do. It would be great it you can explain in your question why you wish to not use what is designed to work, and instead are trying to force something that is designed for some other purpose to work in your setting.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/76681171/2777074